# Include multipages pdf as picture in the center of a a two-column paper

Tags: pdf, two-column, pdfpages, include, includegraphics

I have a two-columns paper in which I want to put a multipages pdf as an "image", in a sheet-wide style (that is, with the pdf contenct centered on the center of the page, and not just in one column).

I have tried something like

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight, pages={1,2}]{document.pdf}
\end{figure*}
```

But only one page is plotted, namely page num. 3.
The pdf has 5 pages, I have tried to also pass the option `pages=-`, or `{1-}`, or any combination of those. 
I have also tried to include the figure as a pdf, using `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, but this is ba, the document turns landscape, and pages are print one over the other.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: I believe \includegraphics can only do one page at a time.  Pdfpages does groups.  Or just use more than one \includegraphics, one for each page (scaled to fit).

Comment: as john said just do one page at a time, also don't do `width=0.9\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight` just specify height or width, not both otherwise you will distort the text

Comment: @JohnKormylo, how would that work for captions?

Comment: Are you trying to pack five pages into one page, or one (input) page per (output) page?  You need a different figure* for each (output) page, and presumably a different \caption.  I really have no idea what you think should be happening with your existing code.